# Refreshing ul or div element when php condition is met

Tags: java, php, html, ajax, opencart

Im very new to programming and I have made the code below to show the links in the li
elements if the php conditions are met. Everything is currently working fine but the problem is that the html elements like the li doesnt refresh when the php condition is met and requires a page refresh. I know this is because of server and client side languanges.
can someone please help me with an ajax code suggestion that fixes this issue.

much appriciated, thx

```
    <!-- checks if product in cart and if yes shows checkout and cart button --> 
    <ul class="main_menu">                                                                         
    <?php if ($this->cart->hasProducts()) { ?>
     <li><a id="top-checkout" href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
     <li><a id="top-cart" href="<?php echo $cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_cart; ?></a></li>

  <?php } else { ?>
<!-- checks if voucher in cart and if yes shows checkout and cart button --> 

   <?php if ($this->cart->hasProducts() || (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) && $this->session->data['vouchers'])) { ?>
      <li><a id="top-checkout" href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
      <li><a id="top-cart" href="<?php echo $cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_cart; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>

<!--       END      -->
<!-- checks if customer is logged in and if yes shows account button -->
      <?php if ($logged) { ?>
      <li><a id="top-account" href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
     <?php } ?>
<!--       END      -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're `<li></li>` elements are in a `<ul></ul>` with an id of `items` (weird id but it'll do for the example)

Then if you're using JQuery do this:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
   $.ajax({
      url: "showListItems.php",
      success: function(dataReceived) {
         $("#items").html(dataReceived);
      }
   });
}
});
```

In your `showListItems.php` file, add this:

```
if ($this->cart->hasProducts()) {
   echo "<li><a id='top-checkout' href='".$checkout."'>".$text_checkout."</a></li>";
   echo "<li><a id='top-cart' href='".$cart."'>".$text_cart."</a></li>";

 } else {
    if (
           $this->cart->hasProducts() || 
           (
             isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) && 
             $this->session->data['vouchers']
           )
        ) 
    {
       echo "<li><a id='top-checkout' href='".$checkout."'>".$text_checkout."</a></li>";
       echo "<li><a id='top-cart' href='".$cart."'>".$text_cart."</a></li>";
    }
 }

 if ($logged) {
    echo "<li><a id='top-account' href='".$account."'>".$text_account."</a></li>";
 }
```

That way, whenever the html page loads, depending on certain conditions, `<li></li>` elements are printed. Furthermore, are there any events you wanna handle like clicks or mouseovers?

If my code has errors (which I'm sure it has a few), could someone alert me of them? And if my code is *completely* incorrect, *please* tell me. Otherwise, test it and enjoy!